# Table creation Error-- Create Table has by default error

Tags: sql-server, create-table

I have a `ORG_TOOLS` table contains a list of `ToolIds` and Status values for each unique OrgId. The stored procedure `sp_ORG_ORGANIZATIONS_CreateDefaultTools` copies the defaults from `OrgId = 0` to a newly specified `OrgId`. It has been noted that during this process, no matter what the default Status values are, the `ToolIds` for the newly specified `OrgId` always have a status of 1.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ORG_TOOLS]
(
     [OrgId] [int] NOT NULL, 
     [ToolId] [int] NOT NULL, 
     [Status] [bit] NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_ORG_TOOLS_Status] DEFAULT ((1)) 
)


CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_ORG_ORGANIZATIONS_CreateDefaultTools
    @OrgId INT
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 

    INSERT INTO ORG_TOOLS (OrgId, ToolId)     
        (SELECT @OrgId, ToolId 
         FROM ORG_TOOLS  
         WHERE OrgId = 0) 
GO
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Your code does exactly what you say - it inserts a new row and sets the OrgId and TooId columns - the value of Status will come from either the default constraint or from a trigger. You complain about the status set to 1 - but that is **exactly** what your code does (assuming this is a complete example). No one can read your mind - if your goal is to set the status to a different value (there's only one other option), you must decide how to achieve that. Change your default constraint or change your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Your code provides the answer - you are setting a default for the field of 1, and in your stored procedure you are not overriding this value. If you want to have a different value stored, you will need to pass that value in. You should also have a new line for the `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO ORG_TOOLS (
    OrgID, 
    ToolID,
    Status
)
(SELECT 
    @OrgId, 
    ToolId,
    [[insert some status value here - perhaps you want a case statement or something, but you have to provide some value to override the default]]
FROM 
    ORG_TOOLS 
WHERE 
    OrgId = 0)
```